# How does Laravel create a 404 view when a route is not defined

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I am working through trying to understand Laravel under the hood, as personally this helps me learn and remember how something works. I cannot work out how the basic 404 works.

I have tried lots of var_dumping in the `Illuminate\RoutingRouteCollection.php` on 157

```
public function match(Request $request)
{
    $routes = $this->get($request->getMethod());

    // First, we will see if we can find a matching route for this current request
    // method. If we can, great, we can just return it so that it can be called
    // by the consumer. Otherwise we will check for routes with another verb.
    $route = $this->matchAgainstRoutes($routes, $request);

    if (! is_null($route)) {
        return $route->bind($request);
    }

    // If no route was found we will now check if a matching route is specified by
    // another HTTP verb. If it is we will need to throw a MethodNotAllowed and
    // inform the user agent of which HTTP verb it should use for this route.
    $others = $this->checkForAlternateVerbs($request);

    if (count($others) > 0) {
        return $this->getRouteForMethods($request, $others);
    }


    throw new NotFoundHttpException;
}
```

It looks as if it must be the NotFoundHttpException, that outputs the 404 view, but I cannot work out how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when page is not found it will throw `NotFoundHttpException`,

there is **abort** method `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation`

```
public function abort($code, $message = '', array $headers = [])
{
    if ($code == 404) {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException($message);
    }

    throw new HttpException($code, $message, null, $headers);
}
```

laravel provides different views for error codes : inside `Exceptions/views` there are views available for

```
401,403,404,419,429,500,503
```

now there is a handler inside `Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions`

inside `Handler.php` :**renderHttpException** method is used to render views according to status code of Exception .

like :

1) renderHttpException: this method checks views exists for given status code then return view .

```
/**
     * Render the given HttpException.
     *
     * @param  \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException  $e
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    protected function renderHttpException(HttpException $e)
    {
        $this->registerErrorViewPaths();

        if (view()->exists($view = "errors::{$e->getStatusCode()}")) {
            return response()->view($view, [
                'errors' => new ViewErrorBag,
                'exception' => $e,
            ], $e->getStatusCode(), $e->getHeaders());
        }

        return $this->convertExceptionToResponse($e);
    }
```

2) registerErrorViewPaths : this method will register path for errors views

```
 /**
     * Register the error template hint paths.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function registerErrorViewPaths()
    {
        $paths = collect(config('view.paths'));

        View::replaceNamespace('errors', $paths->map(function ($path) {
            return "{$path}/errors";
        })->push(__DIR__.'/views')->all());
    }
```

now if you want to make your custom 404 page and want to render it then :

inside `app/Exceptions/Handler.php`

```
 public function render($request, Exception $exception)
 {
        if($this->isHttpException($exception)){
            switch ($exception->getStatusCode()) {

                case 404:
                    return view('path-to-custom404-here');
                    break;

            }
        }
        return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel provides a default [exception handler](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/errors#the-exception-handler) `App\Exceptions\Handler`, which implements a `render` method, which is how the exception is transformed into an HTTP response.

The exception handler is called by the `Http/Kernel.php`, within a try catch block. [See here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/fe2c8a6716195602a924bbe05261eba5820055b4/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php#L111).